# iPhone: Save user data in plist, SQLite or cookie?

Tags: iphone, ios, user-data

My app (like most) is going to be leveraging many remote services... so when a user authenticates themselves, I need to store their username and password (or some kind of flag) so that they don't have to authenticate all over the app.

Where is the best/quickest/easiest place to store this user data?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can still store the username and server URL with NSUserDefaults, but Keychain services is the best idea if you're storing a password.  It's part of the C-Based security framework, and there'a a great wrapper class [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/tree/master/security), to give it an Objective-C API.

To save:

```
NSString *username = @"myname";
NSString *password = @"mypassword";
NSURL *serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];

[SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:username andPassword:password forServiceName:[serverURL absoluteString] updateExisting:YES error:&error]
```

To restore:

```
NSString *passwordFromKeychain = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:username andServiceName:[serverURL absoluteString] error:&error];
```

Comment: I have a project that shares a common library between OSX and iOS. My login management is mostly contained in that shared library. I removed #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> from the header file, and this compiles fine for both OSX and iOS. **I haven't tested the OSX client yet. +1 for reusable code.

Answer (score 8):

NSUserDefaults

Save like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:username    forKey:@"username"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Fetch like this:

```
    NSString *username = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"username"];
    NSString *password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"password"];
```

Comment: And is this an automatic application object that was designed for this exact purpose?

Comment: Yes, NSUserDefaults are for storing one-off user-related values.

Comment: yes--don't use user defaults for saving/retrieving passwords, use Keychain Services as 'sudo rm -rf' suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Storing secure data in an insecure file (user defaults) isn't usually a good idea. Look into Keychain Services, which encrypts sensitive login information and such.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Comment: I just read up on this in the Help and it looks like what I need! I'm assuming that along with a password, you can also store other kinds of information within the keychain?

Comment: I haven't used it much myself, so I can't give a definitive answer, but I'm pretty sure you can store some user information along with the authentication data.  If you're looking for an example, [check out the sample project from the documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html).